# How do you use the NetBeans debugger with grunt-contrib-connect?

Tags: angularjs, debugging, netbeans, yeoman, grunt-contrib-connect

I have a project generated from the Yeoman Angular generator. In WebStorm I setup the project to run 'grunt serve' before debugging and everything just works. When I try this in NetBeans the code doesn't stop at the break points. Is it possible to debug code served from grunt-contrib-connect in NetBeans?